# Exporting large data from database into excel using resultset

Tags: java, excel, database, apache-poi, resultset

I need to export result of a resultset into an excel sheet using java. Resultset contains a table with thousands of rows and multiple columns.
If someone could provide a sample code that will be very useful as I am stuck with this problem. Below is the sample code that I am using to achieve this but somehow not able to get correct data in excel file:-

```
SSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    try {
    setConnection(appDB);

    String queryName="SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES where table_name='table_name'";

    Reporter.addStepLog("----------------------------------- " + queryName.toUpperCase()
            + "\n - Validation Start" + " -----------------------------------");
    ps = con.prepareStatement(queryName, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("employedb");
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from all_tab_columns where table_name='table_name'"); 
      XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
      XSSFCell cell;
      int cc=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      for(int i=1;i<=cc;i++)
      {
          String headerVal=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
          headerValues.add(headerVal);
          cell = row.createCell(i-1);
          cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
      }
      System.out.println(headerValues);
      int i = 1;
      while (resultSet.next())
      {  
          for(int j=1;j<=cc;j++)
          {  
          System.out.println(resultSet.getString(j));
          XSSFRow row1 = spreadsheet.createRow((short) i);
          row1.createCell((short) i).setCellValue(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(j)));
          i++;

      }  
      }

      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("S:\\Downloads\\excel.xlsx"));
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();  
      System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");

}catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Please let me know if the question is not clear as I am new to this forum.

Comment: nothing to do with selenium here, you should remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [MemPOI](https://firegloves.github.io/MemPOI/). Take a look:

```
File file = new File("S:\\Downloads\\excel.xlsx")

PreparedStatement prepStmt = this.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES where table_name='table_name'");
new MempoiBuilder()
                .setFile(file)
                .addMempoiSheet(new MempoiSheet(prepStmt, "employedb"))
                .build()
                .prepareMempoiReportToFile()
                .get();
```

You can easily add a template. Take a look at the doc

Answer (score 0):

To me the Question is not so clear. You want to put calculate data to excel sheet? or you want to get calculatet data from an excel sheet?

I understood you want to put some data into the sheet. 
So you can use several Frameworks to do this. E.g. smartXLS or Apache POI library

Comment: Hubi - I want to export table data from Oracle database into excel using java. I hope now question is clear.

Comment: Are you getting the data out of the database yet?

You can retrieve the data from the database with a database query. For example, you can save it in a list. The Hibernate (ORM) framework is very helpful. 
Now you can iterate over the list and load the data into the Excel file and save it afterwards. For this application I would recommend Hibternate for the database query and SmartXLS for filling the ExcelSheet.

Comment: Hubi- I am using java for extracting the data from the database and storing it in the resultset. Now I want to write all the data from resultset to Excel. I have updated my question to show the code I am using to achieve this but somehow it's not working. Please help if you can provide some code or edit my code.

Comment: unfortunately i'm not so much into POI. but i would recommend you to split the database query and the filling of the excel file into two separate methods

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Double> resultList = new ArrayList();
    resultList.add(250.0);
    resultList.add(300.5);
    resultList.add(500.9);


public void setResultsToSheet(List results) throws Exception {
    WorkBook workBook = new WorkBook();
    int row = 0; //index of first row is 0
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        double result = (double) results.get(i);
        workBook.setNumber(row, 1, result);
        row++;
    }
    workBook.write("X\\yourDestination\\excel.xlsx");
}
```

Hope that can help you anyway.

Comment: Hubi- I will try to implement this tomorrow and let you know.As we are using poi so this might not work but thanks for quick reply.

Comment: okay, let me know. Maybe I can take a closer look and help you.

Comment: Hubi- My above code worked after making minor changes. Thanks for your help.